# database query redirecting to home directory

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I have the simplest database entry that when I hit "submit", it takes me to my home directory and nothing is added to the database. How do I fix it so it inputs the data? I haven't had any problems like this in the past using the same code...

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $text = $_POST['text'];
   $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "******", "********") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
   @mysql_select_db("*****") or die("Couldn't select database");
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall (message) VALUES ('$text')");
 }
?>

<html>
 <form action="post" name="post" id="post">
  <input type="text" id="text" name="text"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
 </form>
</html>
```

I know my password and database name are correct, because when I take away the "form" and "isset", it uploads no problem every time I reload the page:

```
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "******", "*******") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
  @mysql_select_db("********") or die("Couldn't select database");
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall (message) VALUES ('test')");
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<form action="post" name="post" id="post">
```

to

```
<form method="post" name="post" id="post">
```

Action is the page you want the form to submit to
Method is the type (which defaults to get)

Answer (score 1):

Your form<> has no method, try this:

```
<form method="post" name="post" id="post">

</form>
```